# Clang Postorder Traversal

Tags: clang

I want to traverse the AST from a C program in postorder. I've found [RecursiveASTVisitor](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html) so far to traverse a tree in preorder. I thought of overriding the Traverse* methods. However, I think it is quite complicated for a relatively common task. Is there a simpler way to do it or a class which I haven't found yet?

Comment: Because making generic code would be more complicated and probably not as efficient ? So if it's not useful for any of Clang applications, then it's just better off.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it when I went through the docs. Why do you need to traverse the tree in post-order, are you trying to determine when you exit a sub-tree, or is it some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making generic code would be more complicated and probably not as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html#details

> By default, this visitor preorder traverses the AST. If postorder
>   traversal is needed, the shouldTraversePostOrder method needs to be
>   overridden to return true.